# Is it possible to automatically add an import in all new classes in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a class with methods that will be used in many classes. I was wondering if it is possible to have Eclipse automatically import that class when I create a new one for convenience's sake. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the class body template at the menu option `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates` by clicking the *Edit* button of the corresponding template (in your case, `New Java` files) and see what happens when you add the import statement to the template and create a new class.

Answer (score 3):

I know this answer doesn't specifically address the question, but I felt that some people might want this solution instead of the one given.

Instead of creating all files with the imports you expect, you might want a little more flexibility, but still without having to manually add all the imports you need.

In that case, you might consider instead using the Java->Editor->Templates feature.  With this, you could define something like this:

[image: java editor template]

When you want to insert the template, you just type `testimports` where you want them and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

If you have some variations of which blocks of imports you need, this will give you that flexibility.